# In which scripture originally 'ahiṃsā sarvathā sarvadā sarvabhutānāḥ manabhīdroha' sentence was written?

Tags: identification-request, vyasa, ahimsa

> अहिंसा सर्वथा सर्वदा सर्वभुतानाः मनभीद्रोह।
>
> ahiṃsā sarvathā sarvadā sarvabhutānāḥ manabhīdroha।

I read somewhere that it was written by Maharshi Veda Vyasa but the name of scripture in which he wrote it was not mentioned.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Vyasa Bhashya* of Patanjali Yoga Sutras has this verse. Vyasa Muni starts commentary on  **[Sutra 30](https://archive.org/stream/YogaSutramVyasa/YogaSutraVyasa#page/n103) of Sadhana Padha** with this sentence.

> अहिंसासयास्तेयब्रह्मचर्यापरिग्रहा यमाः ॥ ३० ॥ (Sutra)
>
> तत्रा*हिंसा सर्वथा सर्वदा सर्वभूतानामनभिद्रोहः* । उत्तरे च...
> (Commentary)
>
> ahiṃsāsayāsteyabrahmacaryāparigrahā yamāḥ ॥ 30 ॥
>
> tatrā*hiṃsā sarvathā sarvadā sarvabhūtānāmanabhidrohaḥ* । uttare ca...

[Translation](https://archive.org/stream/YogaSutrasOfPatanjaliBhashyaOfVyasaGanganathaJha1907/Yoga%20Sutras%20Of%20Patanjali%20Bhashya%20of%20Vyasa%20Ganganatha%20Jha%201907#page/n99) by Ganganatha Jha:

> Sutra (30) :—Forbearance consists in harmlessness truth, abstinence
> from theft, continence and freedom from avarice.
>
> Com : *Of these "harmlessness'—in no way and at no time  wishing ill
> to any living being*. The following restraints..